# Using importXML in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: xml, xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets

I'm trying to get a value from this page http://socialblade.com/youtube/user/DragonBallzFullHQ the value that I'm trying to get is views for the last 30 days, it always seems to say "Imported xml content can not be parsed"

Here is my google drive importxml code

```
=ImportXML(A1, "//*[@id='youtube-summary-outer-wrap']/div[5]/p/span/text()[1]")
```

A1 is http://socialblade.com/youtube/user/DragonBallzFullHQ

Comment: don't think it's possible on this page since a basic xpath doesn't even work: `=importxml(A1, "//a/@href")`

Answer (score 1):

this should work, i tested it:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//*[@id='afd-header-views-30d']")
```

Answer (score 0):

With the old version of gdrive it works. I have used:
`=ImportXML("http://socialblade.com/youtube/user/dragonballzfullhq";"//div[@class='content-module']/div/div[6]/p/span/text()[1]")`

To create and old version use http://g.co/oldsheets

Answer (score 0):

Usually better use direct approach (not copy xpath from chrome but inspect element):

```
//span[@id="afd-header-views-30d"]/text()
```